# unable to pass data between the views in angularjs through routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angular-ui-router

In my angularjs app, I am trying to pass the data from one cshtml view to another view through routing but in details.cshtml, I don't see the data coming into it though I can see the change in URL

Index.cshtml (View1)

```
  <a href="/#/Details/{{ cid }}" ng-click="SendToCartPage(cartprd)">{{addprodtocart}} </a>
```

Controller.js

```
app.controller('CartController', function ($scope) {
$scope.SendToCartPage = function(cartprd)
{
    var len = cartprd.length - 1;
    $scope.cid = cartprd[len];
}
```

});

Details.cshtml ( I don't see the data coming into the span below)

```
<div ng-controller="CartController">
    <span ng-model="cid">{{cid}}</span>
</div>
```

Myrouting

```
var app = angular.module("productmodule", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.

               when('/Details/:cid', {
                   templateUrl: '/Product/Details',
                   controller: 'CartController'
               });
  }]);
```

**I created a plunker for this. I am unable to send the data from page1 to page2
http://plnkr.co/edit/micM7vlslznEIZXP293Y?p=preview**

Comment: can you paste the controller code for your first view?  Is cid a scope variable in the first controller?

Comment: I am binding the {{addprodtocart}} in the first view                                    

$scope.AddToCart = function (prd) {
        $scope.cartprd = mycart.AddToCart(prd);
        var len = mycart.AddToCart(prd).length - 1;//get the last element of the aray to find the cartcount
        if (mycart.AddToCart(prd)[len] > 0) {
            $scope.addprodtocart = mycart.AddToCart(prd)[len] + " items";
        }
        else {
            $scope.addprodtocart = "No Cart items ! Please add";
        }
    }

Comment: are you binding a value to {{ cid }} in your first controller?

Comment: I am not binding cid to my first controller. I created cid in the second controller

Comment: since you are using {{ cid }} in your view1 , you will have to bind a value to cid in controller corresponding to view1.

Comment: I did that in the code snippet. Please see , I am binding the value of cid in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your controller is instantiated again while clicking on href and the scope is getting recreated & `$scope.cid` is set to undefined.

You could achieve the same by using [**`$routeParams`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) which will give the access to what url contains

In your case it would be `$routeParams.cid`

**Code**

```
app.controller('CartController', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.SendToCartPage = function(cartprd)
  {
    var len = cartprd.length - 1;
    //$scope.cid = cartprd[len];
  }
  $scope.cid = $routeParams.cid;
});
```

**Update**

You should use `$routeParams` service to get data from url

**Code**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/Details/:cid', {
      templateUrl: 'page2.html',
      controller: 'CartController'
    }).when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'page1.html',
      controller: 'CartController'
    });
  }
]);
app.controller('CartController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.myvar = $routeParams.cid; //this will asign value if `$routeParams` has value
  console.log($scope.myvar);
  $scope.Add = function(c) {
    $scope.myvar = c;
  }
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/lGOp5Y6g7GAUffJoojld?p=preview)

Comment: I get  "undefined" in this line                                                                                   $scope.cid = $routeParams.cid;

Comment: `$scope.cid` will available after execution of this line

Comment: I am still unable to pass data from a link in one view 1 to the controller function and then to view 2

Comment: I created a plunker for this. I am unable to send the data from page1 to page2

http://plnkr.co/edit/micM7vlslznEIZXP293Y?p=preview

Comment: OP,Thnaks for the plunkr,I'm heading out of my home so I'll definitely look it.

Comment: cuurently attached plunkr has different code, which you have asked in question..let it be..I'll correct it and will add an answer

Comment: @user3501278 it is very different becuas you are redirecting user to different page. its not an SPA

Comment: hey, i tried to achieve the same thing using SPA but coudln't achieve. If you can give me example using SPA that would be great

Comment: sure, please check it out.